# Upgrading doesn't work on my laptop for 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, upgrade

I'm not able to upgrade to 12.04. I have tried update manager but I get `no new version`.
I've tried terminal it also says `no new version`.

Comment: What is your current version?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to setup to check for new versions, not just LTS releases.  Here's a visual tutorial on how to do this.

**First choose the "Updates Available"  or "System Up to Date" menu at top right.**

[image: Updates Available]

**Then Choose Settings**

[image: Settings]

**Then, choose the setting to check for ANY new versions, and "close" this window when done:**

[image: New Versions]

**Now, check for updates:**

[image: Check]

**Finally, upgrage when ready:**

[image: Upgrade]