# Upgrade to Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, upgrade

When trying to upgrade from Ubuntu 12.04 to 12.10 through the Update Manager, it says there are no updates to install.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have configured your Update Manager software to show upgrades to non-LTS versions. (By default, it will only display alerts when an upgrade to a new LTS version is available.)

Mike Stewart wrote a visual guide in another thread: "[Upgrading doesn't work on my laptop for 12.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/281053/upgrading-doesnt-work-on-my-laptop-for-12-04)" Take a moment to review if this was the cause of your problem. :)